# How to mock a library from the context in Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have the next code in my .ts file:

```
import { getBuildUrl } from '../../service/navigationService';

const appUtils = require('../../utils/appUtils');

describe('Report Title suite tests', () => {

let getHostNameStub = jest.spyOn(appUtils, 'getHostName')
let getOrganizationNameStub = jest.spyOn(appUtils, 'getOrganizationName')
let getProjectNameStub = jest.spyOn(appUtils, 'getProjectName')

  describe('returnBuildUrl', () => {
    getHostNameStub.mockReturnValue("HostNametest")
    getOrganizationNameStub.mockReturnValue("OrganizationTest")
    getProjectNameStub.mockReturnValue("ProjectNameTest")
    
    it('should display title and description without report URL', async () => {
      expect(getBuildUrl("IdTest")).toBeDefined();
      expect(getBuildUrl("IdTest")).toEqual("https://HostNametest/OrganizationTest/ProjectNameTest/_build/results?buildId=IdTest")
    });
  });
});
```

As you can see the appUtils methods are mocked, but I have in the appUtils class the next code: `const VSS_SDK = VSS;`  such as:

```
const VSS_SDK = VSS;

    /**
     * return host name
     */
    export function getHostName() {
      return VSS_SDK.getWebContext().host.authority;
    }
```

`VSS` is a library which is presented in the context of the project

After running the test, I am getting the error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: VSS is not defined

       8 |
       9 | // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    > 10 | const VSS_SDK = VSS;
```

Is it possible to mock the `VSS` library in order to avoid such error?

the getWebContext function looks like this:

```
    /**
        * Get the web context from the parent host
        */
function getWebContext(): WebContext;
```

And the WebContext interface:

```
interface WebContext {
    account: HostContext;
    /**
    * Information about the Collection used in the current request (may be null)
    */
    collection: HostContext;
    /**
    * Information about the current request context's host
    */
    host: ExtendedHostContext;
    /**
    * Information about the project used in the current request (may be null)
    */
    project: ContextIdentifier;
    /**
    * Information about the team used in the current request (may be null)
    */
    team: TeamContext;
    /**
    * Information about the current user
    */
    user: UserContext;
}
```

With the suggested solution I am getting the next error:

```
Type '() => { host: { authority: string; }; }' is not assignable to type '() => WebContext'.
  Type '{ host: { authority: string; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'WebContext': account, collection, project, team, userts(2322)
VSS.SDK.d.ts(201, 14): The expected type comes from property 'getWebContext' which is declared here on type 'typeof VSS
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see `VSS` is a global variable that is not known for jest runner.

You need to provide a way for jest to see that var.

You have two options to configure that:

- [Setup-files](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array)
- [Setup-files-after-env](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array)

All you need is to edit your jest configuration and add one of the options there as follows

```json
{
  ...
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/setup.js'],
  ...
}
```

And you can declare any global variable in that `setup.js` file or do whatever you want before your test gets executed (it's all up to you).

```js
global.VSS = {
  getWebContext: () => {
    return {
      host: {
        authority: 'My-authority'
      }
    };
  }
};
```

Make sure you add all properties and methods you might need in your test run.

Comment: Thank you so much, I added more info to the initial question, sorry I am beginner of Jest, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Oh, that is because you use typescript and I assumed it was JS. Try doing the same but with `setup.ts` and make sure the body of `global.VSS = {...}` will have compatible types.

But I still don't get why you have a global variable in the first place. Can't you import the VSS normally?

Comment: When I do import { ContextHostType } from 'vss-web-extension-sdk/lib/Context/ContextHostType';
I get Cannot find module 'vss-web-extension-sdk/lib/Context/ContextHostType' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Comment: Does your code run or it's just the unit test is failing?

Comment: just unit testing, not sure how to inject vss-web-extension-sdk/ on jest, it is not recognized

Comment: The way I provided it is how you inject global variables in Jest you just need to fix the type declaration for it. A very simple solution(but not recommended) would be to suppress it with `@ts-ignore` to get rid of the TS error or use `js` extension in your test file

Comment: I am getting the next error: error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature. I also defined the structure this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75701935/jest-reference-error-global-variable-is-not-defined-error-when-running-test but I am getting the error: Jest reference error, global variable is not defined error when running test